# Which Machine Learning algorithm should I use for gender tagging of words in NLP?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, natural-language-processing, classification

I have a dataset of about 26,000 words along with their gender tags [m, f or any]. Which ML algorithm should I use for Gender Tagging/Classification purpose. How should I go about it? What should be the input features?

Given a word , it's Part Of Speech tag and in some cases the singularity I am trying to predict the gender of the word.

Comment: I would test test out several different algorithms (classifiers) based on Neural Networks, on Regression (logistic regression), Decision Trees... then select the best one using cross-validation. Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Classification_algorithms.

Comment: I guess this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html also would be helpful.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/283907/2921, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76436/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, even though it is on-topic here, because it was cross-posted on Stats.SE.